# How do I speed up the animation time for switching between desktop spaces?

Tags: macos, spaces, defaults

Is there a way to speed up the animation time for switching between spaces? (Or maybe turning them off?). Preferably without buying a third party app. Maybe there's an option defaults.

I'm on Sierra 10.12.6.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a duplicate of [Speed up Mission Control animations in macOS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253756/speed-up-mission-control-animations-in-macos-sierra)

Here's the short answer. If you want extremely fast animations, this is your defaults write command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0.1
```

Comment: thanks but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: This does nothing.

Comment: This only works if you have a single screen, not multiple monitors.

Comment: Thanks! This does work for my plugged monitor (macOS Catalina 10.15.7)

Comment: This made the switch faster on Monteray 12.6, but still slower than what I'm used to in Ubuntu :(

Comment: As of Ventura this does’t seem to do anything