# How can I make all animations instant?

Tags: macos, catalina, animation

How do I get rid of these kinds of animations:

- Switching spaces
- Minimising windows
- Entering Mission Control
- Exiting Mission Control

in macOS Catalina 10.15?

Comment: Why is this down voted?  It's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: How is this question different than existing ones? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253756/ https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329536/ (which all seem to be a grab bag of specific preference tweaks)

Comment: Just being pragmatic here...the dupe link is about *speeding up* animations, not "getting rid of" and only one answer vaguely addresses Mission Control.  It talks about "the old behavior" but if someone isn't familiar with "the old behavior" how would they know what that is?

Answer (score 2):

Something which *might* help (but it doesn't go all the way) is to enable the 'Reduce motion' option in the System Preferences section Accessibility:

[image]